# Redirect from https to http or from http to https?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https, http

We have a WordPress blog, google is indexing `http` as well as `https` urls. Now we are considering to either redirect `https` to `http`, or to use `https` and redirect all `http` traffic there. And how can we make all necessary changes to our WordPress installation?

Comment: why do you need to redirect https to http?

Comment: @Vishwa because google is indexing both https and http

Comment: you dont need to add both to search console. google **always** prefer https over http. you dont need to add redirect to make google crawl your http version anyways

Comment: @Vishwa you suggest do nothing? or make website HTTPS?

Comment: make website https. and make sure every resource(stylesheet,scripts and images etc..) are loaded over secure connection, or otherwise you'll get mixed content issue. you dont need to add a redirection for google, that's what I was saying. *p.s*:downvote is not from me

Comment: @Vishwa Thanks. it doesnt need to redirect http to https?

Comment: it does. make sure all your permalinks are updated and media files, css, js files are loading over https.

Comment: @Vishwa Thanks a lot .

Comment: glad to be a help :)

Comment: A verry good answer can be found here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console

Comment: I'm curious... if your site is accessible by both HTTP and HTTPS why were you choosing to favor HTTP over HTTPS? Does your site not work properly over HTTPS? I didn't downvote either, but I imagine this is because... `.htaccess` specific questions are generally off-topic on WordPress SE (these are better suited to the [Webmasters Stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)). You don't give any specifics as to what "doesn't work"? Errors? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? And... in 2019 there should be no need to redirect HTTPS to HTTP - so what you are suggesting is against all recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

If available always use `https`, it is securer for obvious reasons, it is better received by search engines and browsers nowadays, it is just overall preferable.

**1 Backup**

Should go without saying, but backup your database. There is always a possibility that something goes wrong. Additionally, make sure you have access – ssh, ftp, etc – to your files, and you have a possibility to access – ssh (mysql, wp-cli), phpmyadmin, etc – the database.

**2 Set URL**

Either under *Dashboard > Settings > General*:

[image]

Or use constants in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME','https://example.com' ); 
define( 'WP_SITEURL','https://example.com' );
```

**3 Update database**

Either use the Search Replace DB tool:

- https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
- https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Or make use the WP-CLI command `search-replace`:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Example: `wp search-replace 'http://example.test' 'http://example.com'`

Both above options have an option to dry run, test, before making changes.

Bonus, this plugin gets recommended a lot by people I generally trust:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Note: I personally have no experience with the plugin; I'm adding it for completeness’ sake.

**4 Enforce redirecting to https**

Either via adding the following lines to the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or you can generally set this via your server administration gui, so plesk, cpanel, webmin or whatever your hosting provider is offering.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this code in the **wp-config.php** file to define your new URL.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com'); //Enter your new URL
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com'); //Enter your new URL
```